# How to sent text string to service?

Tags: delphi, service

I have a desktop application and a service. How can i send string from desktop application into my service and handle it in a service?

I don't want use sockets because it may be blocked by Windows Firewall.

Comment: you can use a file-based command, when file is modified/created, read it, process it, delete it/change a flag in it.

Comment: if file or printersharing is enabled (Port 445) you can use Named Pipes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918985/interprocess-communication-with-a-win32-service

Comment: Firewall wont block local communication. Anyway, your best bet is shared memory + appropriate sync events.

Comment: Tried Cromis IPC ? Delphi-centriic library around named pipes.

Or on may use combination of shared memory and named semaphores a la Firebird XNet, if really in need for if hi-throughput multithreaded data traffic is a must.

Comment: @user539484 that depends upon firewall.

Comment: @Arioch 'The, the one OP has concened about is smart enough to not "protect" an internal loopback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to use network transport then probably the simplest way to do cross-session IPC is to use a named pipe. The main thing to take care over is that you will need to supply security attributes when creating the named pipe. Without doing so you won't succeed in cross-session communications. My code to do so looks like this:

```
var
  SA: TSecurityAttributes;
....
SA.nLength := SizeOf(SA);
SA.bInheritHandle := True;
ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(
  'D:(A;OICI;GRGW;;;AU)',//discretionary ACL to allow read/write access for authenticated users
  SDDL_REVISION_1,
  SA.lpSecurityDescriptor,
  nil
);
FPipe := CreateNamedPipe(
  '\\.\pipe\MyPipeName',
  PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
  PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE or PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE or PIPE_WAIT,
  PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
  0,//don't care about buffer sizes, let system decide
  0,//don't care about buffer sizes, let system decide
  100,//timout (ms), used by clients, needs to cover the time between DisconnectNamedPipe and ConnectNamedPipe
  @SA
);
LocalFree(HLOCAL(SA.lpSecurityDescriptor));
if FPipe=ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE then begin
  ;//deal with error
end;
```